# Uniqueness of left-invariant Borel probability measure on compact groups

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, topological-groups, haar-measure

On a compact topological group, consider two left-invariant probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ defined on the Borel sigma-algebra. Is it true that they coincide?

It is classical that the Haar measure is unique (up to scalar multiplication, that I've ruled out by considering probability measures), but the definition of Haar measure usually includes some form of regularity (inner or outer), and the uniqueness is only proved under this assumption (see classical textbooks such as Halmos, Cohn, Bogachev, Fremlin).

Without regularity assumption, one can readily check that continuous functions have the same integral with respect to $\mu$ and $\nu$, but it's not enough a priori to deduce that $\mu = \nu$ as there is no reason why continuous functions should be dense in $L^1$, say.

My guess is that there is no uniqueness in this generality, but I don't have a counterexample.

Context: I am formalizing uniqueness of Haar measures in the Lean theorem prover, and I would like to do it right.

Comment: I expect this to fail in general although I don't have a counterexample, but let me point out that there are no counterexample for metrizable groups. Indeed a metrizable compact group is Polish and on a Polish space finite Borel measures are regular (inner and outer) and tight (see Kechris, *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*, 17.10 and 17.11)

Comment: Yes, whenever the topology is second-countable (for instance in the metrizable case) then all Borel measures are regular and the issue disappears. The question is really for big compact groups.

Comment: I think uniqueness might hold in this case without regularity (and more generally for $\sigma$-compact locally compact groups) because of Halmos' theorem that Haar measure is completion regular i.e. inner regular wrt zero sets- see Fremlin's Measure Theory Chapter 44, "443M Theorem (Halmos 50)".

Comment: If I understand correctly, Halmos theorem requires a regularity assumption with respect to compact sets to start with (that's part of the definition of Haar measure in Fremlin). So I don't see how to use this theorem if I start from a possibly wild measure, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uniqueness does hold, as a direct consequence of Halmos's theorem that Haar measure is completion regular.

Here are pointers to relevant parts of [Fremlin's book](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mtcont.htm). "Completion regular" is defined in 411Jb. Halmos's theorem is "443M Theorem (Halmos 50)". It applies to any Haar measure, which is by definition (441D) a non-zero left-invariant quasi-Radon measure. Quasi-Radon (411Ha) means it's complete and every open set is measurable, plus other conditions.

It suffices to show that any such measure is equal to Haar measure. Accordingly, let $\mu$ be normalized Haar measure on $G,$ restricted to Borel sets, and let $\nu$ be an arbitrary left-invariant Borel probability measure. You know $\mu$ and $\nu$ agree on integrals of continuous functions, and hence on the measures of zero sets. Let $X\subseteq G$ be a Borel set. Since Haar measure is completion regular, for any
$\epsilon>0$ there is a zero set
$Z\subseteq X$ with $\mu(Z)\geq \mu(X)-\epsilon.$
Hence $\nu(X)\geq\nu(Z)=\mu(Z)\geq \mu(X)-\epsilon.$ Applying the same argument to the complement $G\setminus X$ we get
$\nu(X)\leq \mu(X)+\epsilon.$ Taking $\epsilon\to 0$ shows that $\mu(X)=\nu(X).$

Comment: What is the meaning of "zero set"? (I first thought of "set of measure zero" but it sounds senseless here, both for Haar and $\mu$.) Does it mean zero set of a continuous function? (These are closed subsets, and for $G$ metrizable it is the same as a closed subset.)

Comment: A "zero set" is a set of the form $\{x : f(x)=0\}$, where $f : G \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function.  In the setting here, where $G$ is not metrizable, the zero sets may generate a sigma-algebra strictly smaller than the Borel sets.

Comment: Thanks! I had missed the trick that it is enough to know that the usual Haar measure is regular, and that one doesn't need any regularity information on the other measure $\nu$. Although in the end this argument proves that $\nu$ is also regular, of course.

Comment: For the record, this argument has now been formalized in the Mathlib library for Lean, [here](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib4/blob/master/Mathlib/MeasureTheory/Measure/Haar/Unique.lean), in the following general version: consider $\mu$ and $\mu'$ two left-invariant Borel measures on a locally compact group, which are finite on compact sets, positive on open sets, and normalized in the same way. Then $\mu(A) = \mu'(A)$ whenever $A$ has compact closure, or is open.

Answer (score 1):

[This was too long to be a comment, but is basically just a recontextualization of the other answer.]

If you use Baire measures rather than Borel measures (which is probably the more natural setting without any countability or metrizability assumptions), then all of the required regularity properties to apply uniqueness of (Baire) Haar measure automatically hold, so this question is really about uniqueness of Borel extensions of Baire Haar measure.

While Fremlin uses a definition of "completion regular" that fits better with the glut of regularity properties he considers in that chapter of his book, for Baire measures there is another definition that is more obviously applicable here (and closer to the form Halmos originally proved): a Baire measure is completion regular if its completion measures all Borel sets. This implies that a completion regular Baire measure has a unique Borel extension (without any assumptions of regularity properties on this extension).

Comment: ... and without assuming that the Borel extension is invariant under left-translation ?

Comment: Correct, this would only require the Baire restriction to be left-invariant.